# Root Files System Not Defined

Tags: installation, partitioning

I am new to ubuntu, and was installing ubuntu 11.04 from a CD. I booted up the CD and went to the installation process. I got to the step where it asked me to allocate my drive space. The window above with the columns titled mount, drive, etc., was completely empty. I didn't know what to do, so I pressed continue anyway. Another window appeared saying that the root file system was not defined, and that I needed to define it from the partitioning menu, which was blank! I have looked everywhere for the solution, and there is a lot of talk about setting the mount point to "/". I understand that that, but where do I set it! I also have not gone through the same installation windows as everyone else. 
(My installation process seems to skip the window where you decide to install ubuntu or try it from the CD.)

Please Help!

Comment: If you can, install 11.10 instead of 11.04.  It probably won't make a difference with the installation problem you're having, but it's later and generally more up-to-date.  Now, as for setting the mount point, it's tough to know what you're seeing since it appears to be different than most others, but on the same page where you have partitioning choices, there is usually a drop-down box that gives you a choice for setting the mount point, and one of those choices is "/".

Comment: I tried that, but when there is only one option in the scroll down menu,"/dev/sda".

Answer (score 2):

Some RAID code was interfering with the installation. I opened a terminal and entered

```
sudo apt-get remove dmraid
```

After I entered it, I tried the installation again, and it worked. I was able to select my partition and run it along with windows.

Comment: Actually, I eventually replaced Windows Vista with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it couldn't read your hard disk.  Press Ctrl+Alt+F2/F3/F4, find the debug output, and look for errors.

Using a newer version of Ubuntu may also solve it.

Comment: Those commands don't do anything for some reason. Alt+F2 opens a window letting you run applications, that is it.

Comment: Oops, I forgot you're in X.  Use Ctrl+Alt not just Alt.  But really, try the newer version.

Comment: It is reading my hard disk as "/dev/sda1". But in the installation menu, I can't select that from the table.

Comment: You need to look for errors relating to the partitioner.  But really, try the newer version before wasting a lot of time on this.

Comment: I tried the newer version before, using wubi, and from a flash drive that I created. I kept getting the same errors that I'm geting now. Because I don't have a CD burner( my drive only reads CDs) I thought that using a later version would be okay, just so that I could use the CD installation. I only have the CD for Ubuntu 11.04, it's a Linux format DVD.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your last comment.  I suggest putting 11.10 or 12.04 beta on a flash drive and installing from that, without using Wubi.  You should still be able to find errors from the partitioner in the Ctrl+Alt+F2 console (or it might not be F2, I can't remember and can't find it on Google).  There should be an error visible in the log that should explain the problem.

Comment: How large does the flash drive need to be?